Can't update old iPad to last supported version of the iOS-version this device supports?
I have an old iPad that is stuck at iOS 14 (?). When I try to update apps on this device I often get a warning that the current version of the app requires a newer version of iOS but I can download the last supported version. However, this doesn't work https://imgur.com/a/fy65Ge2 (screen recording of the process).
How can I fix this? Clearly it is supported but it doesn't work??

What exact model of iPad is this?

What's the exact version you're on?  Does this only happen with Google Maps (per your video) or is it with all apps that have a newer version?

@fsb I have also tried with iWork Numbers and Pages, with the same result. iOS 12.5.7 (the last supported version)

@d-b There's a chance that something is just broken with the App Store because of how old the iOS version you have (5 years old) is

@Ezekiel Could be, but I have had this problem for years, maybe 5, though I haven't really come around and ask about it until now.
